# Как из лога выкусывать и отображать кусок строки?

Tags: bash, shell, grep, awk

Нужно выкусывать из лога определенные куски строк. 
Ещё было бы супер, чтобы не отображались повторения. но не обязательно.

такой командой вывожу нужные мне строки из лога:

```
$ tail -f /var/adm/messages | grep 'KHARKOV.*errcode=-28'

Nov  1 18:19:27 SSCK01 dhcpd[14507]: [ID 687704 local7.error] [tid:55] ERR DHCP(304) Authentication of user KHARKOV-K20 PON 1/1/01/03:11.1.1 failed (errcode=-28).
Nov  1 18:19:27 SSCK01 dhcpd[14507]: [ID 687704 local7.error] [tid:7] ERR DHCP(304) Authentication of user KHARKOV-K13 PON 1/1/05/01:27.1.1 failed (errcode=-28).
Nov  1 18:19:27 SSCK01 dhcpd[14507]: [ID 687704 local7.error] [tid:20] ERR DHCP(304) Authentication of user KHARKOV-K13 PON 1/1/02/02:45.1.1 failed (errcode=-28).
```

Нужно выводить кусок:

```
KHARKOV-K20 PON 1/1/01/03:11.1.1
KHARKOV-K13 PON 1/1/05/01:27.1.1
KHARKOV-K13 PON 1/1/02/02:45.1.1
```

Нашел как с помощью команды cut выкусить кусок строки перед 16м пробелом

```
$tail -f /var/adm/messages | grep 'KHARKOV.*errcode=-28' | cut -d' ' -f16 

KHARKOV-K20
KHARKOV-K13
KHARKOV-K13
```

Как остальное вывести не могу найти.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте с помощью `awk`:

```
$tail -f /var/adm/messages | grep 'KHARKOV.*errcode=-28' | awk ' {print  $15,$16,$17} '
```

Первое описание, которе нашел – http://rus-linux.net/MyLDP/consol/awk.html

### UPD

Что бы еще оставить только уникальные строки, можно так:

```
$tail -f /var/adm/messages | grep 'KHARKOV.*errcode=-28' | awk ' {print  $15,$16,$17} ' | sort | uniq
```

Comment: Спасибо, тоже вариант при помощи awk . Поправил немного                     tail -f /var/adm/messages | grep 'KHARKOV.*errcode=-28' | awk ' {print $15,$16,$17} '

Comment: @VadimPirx, да, опечатался, спасибо, поправил в ответе

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался по внимательнее cut
Такая конструкция выводит то что мне надо. 
Вывод строки слева от 16го 17го и 18го пробела:

```
$ tail -f /var/adm/messages | grep 'KHARKOV.*errcode=-28' | cut -d' ' -f16,17,18

KHARKOV-K20 PON 1/1/01/03:11.1.1
KHARKOV-K13 PON 1/1/05/01:27.1.1
KHARKOV-K13 PON 1/1/02/02:45.1.1
```

Теперь нужно чтобы не выводились повторы символов после 'KHARKOV-'

И кто знает как выводить результаты этой команды на web морду?

Comment: Повторы, в смысле -K13 д.б. только в одной строке (независимо от даты/времени)?

Comment: ну строки типа KHARKOV-K13 PON 1/1/05/01:27.1.1   и  KHARKOV-K13 PON 1/1/05/02:27.1.1  разные. должны выводится обе

Comment: Тогда достаточно `sort -u` к результатам `| cut ...`

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение.
вывод команды пишу в файл result а потом из этого файла cat уникальные строки

```
$ tail -f /var/adm/messages | grep 'KHARKOV.*errcode=-28' | cut -d' ' -f16,17,18 >> result

$ cat result | sort | uniq
```

Comment: Это можно делать в той же строке `tail -f /var/adm/messages | grep 'KHARKOV.*errcode=-28' | cut -d' ' -f16,17,18 | sort -u`

Answer (score 0):

```
tail -f /var/adm/messages | grep 'KHARKOV.*errcode=-28' | awk ' {print  $15,$16,$17} ' | sort | uniq
tail -f /var/adm/messages | grep 'KHARKOV.*errcode=-28' | cut -d' ' -f16,17,18 | sort -u
```

не работают такие конструкции, видимо на лету не может сортировать строки.

Работает если tail -f заменить на cat
вычитал кусок лога за сутки (второе ноября) и его уже обработал, сделал два файла, result - всё скопом и resuls_sort - сортировка.

```
cat /var/adm/messages | grep 'Nov  2.*KHARKOV.*errcode=-28' | awk ' {print  $15,$16,$17} ' >result | cat result | sort | uniq  >result_sort
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tail -f /var/adm/messages | awk '/KHARKOV.*errcode=-28/ { print $15, $16, $17 }' | sort -u
tail -f /var/adm/messages | awk -F'KHARKOV-| failed' '{ print $2 }' | sort -u
```

Я так поняла главное в сортировке на лету. Попробуйте вот этот вариант

```
tail -f /var/adm/messages | awk '/KHARKOV.*errcode=-28/ { if (!t[$0]++) print $15, $16, $17 }'
```

Эта команда заменяет grep, cut и uniq. Выводит уникальные строки но без дополнительной сортировки, в том порядке как поступают на вход конвеера